# Ansible web server role versioning strategy for several environments

Tags: git, version-control, ansible, configuration-management

we are currently starting to adopt ansible as our cm tool of choice across all our envs, we are looking into configuring an nginx server accross several dev, qa, uat and prod environments, we are looking into leveraging the templating module in order to enable ansible to deploy to each of these environments by using variables per env, what would be the best practice regarding the versioning strategy of the whole platform?

Should we have 1 branch for each env? so each env would have his variable file and each change to it would trigger a new version just for the env? or the best would be to have all the variables for all envs and a change would trigger a new version of everything? This assuming that we cannot have the same cofiguration for every env (yet),

Best Regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, maybe DevOps.SE would be a appropriate, but as is the question looks too broad for any SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’s better use **separate branches for each env** so that an env can run against with others.

And using different branches can make it more traceable for a certain environment versions. It’s not the usual manners to update all environments at the same time (if your situation is update all environment at the same time, you can put all the variables together).

Comment: got it, yeah i wasn't really thinking on the scenarios where i would actually use the source i was versioning, it makes a lot of sense.